# Asp.Net .Contains all words in any order

Tags: asp.net, contains

I've got a search box which I need to check all words in it against a a string array

So far I've got the following code

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To wordList.Length - 1

            If wordList(i).Contains(TextBox1.Text) Then
                Dim item As String() = New String(0) {}
                item(0) = wordList(i)

                items.Add(item)
            End If

        Next
```

This checks if the words contain what's in the textbox in the order it is input but not individual words in any order.

Any ideas how I can check every word in any order and only show words from `wordList` that contain ALL words?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LINQ:

```
Dim words As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(' 'c);
If words.All(AddressOf someString.Contains) Then
```

If you don't want to match text in the middle, you'll need to use a regex:

```
If words.All(Function(W) Regex.IsMatch(someString, "\b" + Regex.Escape(w) + "\b"))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer - I'm getting a `All is not a member of System.Array` any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try with this code :

```
result = from  item in wordList 
            where item.Contains(TextBox1.Text)
            select item;
```